# Singularity/residue of $\frac{z}{\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I have to find the type of singularities and their residues of $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sin(z)}$.

I know $z=0$ is a removable singularity, so residue is zero. The other singularities are at $z=k\pi$, and I wanted to calculate the residues by limit:

$$\lim_{z\to k\pi} (z-k\pi)f(z) = \lim_{z\to k\pi} z \lim_{z\to k\pi} \frac{z-k\pi}{\sin(z)} = k\pi \lim_{z\to k\pi} \frac{1}{\cos(z)} = k\pi (-1)^k$$

Which is wrong since the answer is just $(-1)^k$ according to the teacher. So my question is where do I go wrong? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, I think the teacher's answer is wrong.

Comment: Your calculation is right, your teacher is wrong. Way more interesting is to ask why L'Hospital can be used with complex functions...and it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You result is true. In $z=k\pi$ the residues by l'hospital rule are
$$\lim_{z\to k\pi} (z-k\pi)f(z) = \lim_{z\to k\pi} \frac{z^2-k\pi z}{\sin z} = \lim_{z\to k\pi} \frac{2z-k\pi}{\cos z} = (-1)^k k\pi$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.